# How to pass viewData back to the controller from partial view?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a main view using several partial Views.
Each of these partials use a different model and have post action.
My problem is I need one property from my main view's model to be used in one of my partials.

The partial view which I need to pass this property view is the last stage in the process.
The application reaches a partial view that contains a switch statement , based on the status on the item being queried, decides which partial will be rendered.

I have the property passing that far and even have it included in the Renderaction for the partial but I don't know how to retrieve it in the controller, PartialViewResult.

In the main view:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("StatusForm", Model.HeadingDataModel.Status, new ViewDataDictionary { { "PurchaseOrderNumber", Model.AccordionModel.LtsSpecific.PurchaseOrderNumber } });}
```

PurchaseOrderNumber is what I'm after. The value gets passed to the next stage:

```
@{
   var obj = ViewData["PurchaseOrderNumber"];  
 }
```

And within the same view:

```
Html.RenderAction("FinishedCalibrationForm", obj);
```

How can I retreive this in my controller ?? The following is not correct I know, but you get the idea.

```
public PartialViewResult FinishedCalibrationForm( string obj)
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Html.RenderAction` or `Html.Action` is largely the same as `Url.Action`. There's many different overloads, but essentially, the first parameter is the action name, the second parameter is going to be either the controller name or an anonymous object of route values, and the third parameter will be an anonymous object of route values *if the second parameter was used for the controller name*.

Anyways, whatever you pass in the route values will be used to find and call the associated action, which includes parameters for the action. So, for your example:

```
Html.RenderAction("FinishedCalibrationForm", new { obj = obj })
```

Would properly pass `obj` into your action method. As you have it now, it's going to interpret the value of `obj` as the controller name the action is within, which is obviously not correct.

Comment: Believe or not I just figured it out, you are correct.cheers.